# Printing unescaped white space to shell

Tags: python, escaping

Consider this line of Python code:

```
s = "This string has \n\r whitespace"
```

How do I make

`print s`

give me

`This string has \n\r whitespace`

*instead of*

```
This string has
whitespace
```

as it does now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

do you want a raw string ?

```
s = r"This string has \n\r whitespace"
```

or to transform special characters to it's representation?

```
repr(s)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
 print s.encode('string-escape')
```

Answer (score 4):

You want the `repr` function.

```
print repr(s)
```

Comment: Note: this will also print `'` at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: The OP may or may not also want the quotes that `repr()` would add.

Comment: That prints `'This string has \n\r whitespace'`, with quotes, so the output isn't exactly what the OP specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's formatting capabilities to print the string in its "[raw](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)" form:

```
print "%r" % s
```

You can also create a string in raw form like this:

```
s = r'This string has \n\r whitespace'
```

and Python will handle escaping the backslashes so that that is exactly what you get:

```
print s # outputs "This string has \n\r whitespace"
```